# If i can't get context how can i use like Picaso?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, picasso

I use firbase-ui display a `recyclerView` , it extends Activity  , just like this:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatItem, ExpenseHolder>
                (ChatItem.class, R.layout.chat_room_list, ExpenseHolder.class, secondRoot) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ExpenseHolder viewHolder, ChatItem chatItem, int position) {
                viewHolder.setValues(chatItem);
            }
        };
        recyclerChat.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);//just let the latest data below
        //recyclerChat.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));//增加橫線
        recyclerChat.setAdapter(adapter);

        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerChat.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Here is my ExpenseHolder , i find it must be static or it will cause crash

```
    public static class ExpenseHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private final TextView textRightMsg;
            private final TextView textLeftMsg;
            private final TextView rightTime;
            private final ImageView rightImage;

            public ExpenseHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                textRightMsg = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textRight);
                textLeftMsg = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textLeft);
                rightTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rightTime);
                rightImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rightImage);
            }

            public void setValues(ChatItem chatItem) {
                String myName = chatItem.getName();
                if (myName.equals(userName)) {
                    textRightMsg.setText(chatItem.getMsg() + "(" + chatItem.getName() + ")");
                    rightTime.setText(chatItem.getTime());
// I don't know how to get context in this class                    
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(rightImage);
                } else {
                    textLeftMsg.setText(chatItem.getMsg() + "(" + chatItem.getName() + ")");
                }
            }
        }
```

When i want to set a image by using Picaso , i find that i can't get `contex`

I try to set global `privat static Context contex;` , it carashes that show error context is null .

Here is my resource that is what i want to display
[image]

How can i show the image that resource is url and in static environment ?

Comment: try `textRightMsg .getContext()`

Comment: thanks !  it works ,i got it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way..

```
Picasso.with(rightImage.getContext()).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(rightImage);
```

Comment: downloading images is a long time background process so be careful when you're using activity context. you can cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

You can get context from `itemView`

```
Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(rightImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even get context by passing it into the constructor of `ExpenseViewHolder`

```
public static class ExpenseHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView textRightMsg;
        private final TextView textLeftMsg;
        private final TextView rightTime;
        private final ImageView rightImage;
        private Context context;

        public ExpenseHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            this.context = context;

            textRightMsg = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textRight);
            textLeftMsg = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textLeft);
            rightTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rightTime);
            rightImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rightImage);
        }

        public void setValues(ChatItem chatItem) {
            String myName = chatItem.getName();
            if (myName.equals(userName)) {
                textRightMsg.setText(chatItem.getMsg() + "(" + chatItem.getName() + ")");
                rightTime.setText(chatItem.getTime());
// I don't know how to get context in this class                    
                Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(rightImage);
            } else {
                textLeftMsg.setText(chatItem.getMsg() + "(" + chatItem.getName() + ")");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think that it's may be can solve the issue too , but when i try it , it shows error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Context must not be null.

Comment: then better to go with context of the view. Because I just saw, that object of viewholder is initiated automatically rather than your using your own constructor.